# How to access global variable name inside app.component.ts

Tags: angular, angular8

I ahve declared global varibale name inside index.html page.I am trying to get that variable value inside app.component.ts file.How to do it?

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'my-app',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
name = 'Angular 6';

constructor() {
console.log(test);
}
}
```

index.html:

```
<script>
  var test = 'value';
</script>
<my-app>loading</my-app>
```

Demo:https://stackblitz.com/edit/input-output-angular-7h5uaa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: `console.log((window as any).test);` But why would you need such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

Well, This is not the way usually Angular developers deal with shared variables. It's better to implement a singleton service and put these variables inside it or if this variable is read-only you can put it inside the environment file.

But if you insist on doing this, you can create a `typing.d.ts` file in your root folder and put the following code inside it:

`declare let test;`

with this approach, the Angular compiler would ignore the error and you can run your code without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I used following blog to get window object in components as service
it worked for me , please check

https://juristr.com/blog/2016/09/ng2-get-window-ref/